# How do I get all entries of a class if it's related set contains an arbitrary item?

Tags: django, django-orm

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ...

class Page(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    note = models.ForeignKey(Note)


class Note(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

From the example above, how can I obtain all Books instances that contain an arbitrary Note?

```
my_note = Note.objects.get(name="Arbitrary")

pages_with_my_note = Page.objects.filter(note=my_note)

books_with_my_note = Book.objects.filter( ??? )
```

I'm trying

`pages_with_my_note.values_list("book").distinct()` but I get:

> TypeError: distinct_sql() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'params'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply,

```
books_with_my_note = Book.objects.filter(page__note__name='Arbitrary').distinct()
```

**Reference:**

- [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Book has no page property

Comment: I don't get it, can you elaborate more?

Comment: "django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'page' into field."

Comment: Can you show ***the "actual" model definition***? It might be the issue with the *`related_name`*